# Microsoft word/office dictionary thesaurus via python script

Tags: python, nltk

I was wondering if it is possible to use the dictionary installed with Microsoft office via a python script. I really would like to use the thesaurus to find synonyms for certain words.  I know I could use the nltk package, but I will not be able to install it on every system due to a very crabby systems admin.  Maybe there is another lexicon installed with windows that could be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

Since the computers in question already have python, you can install the NLTK for your own use without admin privileges. The NLTK itself is pretty small, but you can further trim it down to produce a customized installation that only contains the modules you need for this task.

You don't say what resource you were planning to use as a dictionary/thesaurus replacement, but perhaps its format is simple enough to process without the nltk. If so, you can just get the file from `nltk_data` on your own computer and copy it to other systems.